# CAML query builder that supports inner joins?

Tags: caml-query

I'm Looking for a query builder that can assist me in creating CAML queries that will contain inner joins.

Does anything like this exist?

Update: To ask my question more clearly, I am looking for a software package that assists in writing these join queries more easily. Previously we had CAML Builder, but that doesn't support joins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this was a feature added in SharePoint 2010. Take a look at the [SPQuery.Joins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.joins%28office.14%29.aspx) property, and here's an [example by Tobias Zimmergren](http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2010/01/04/sp-2010-list-joins-amp-spquery-enchancements.aspx).

This is also possible using [LINQ to SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535491.aspx), which generates the appropriate CAML behind the scenes.

Comment: i found that linq to query has an issue in a high volume scenarios.  Be careful and use with caution.